# add multiple twitter connections to one user on spring social project

Tags: spring, twitter-oauth, spring-social

In my project, I need to add more than one twitter accounts to one User so that I can search all time lines as I required.
I have managed to add one twitter connection to a user , now I want to extend it to multiple accounts. is it possible with spring social ?